# Ubuntu 12.04 and bind9 not responding to queries

Tags: server, bind

I'm trying to set up an authoritative DNS server with bind9 (9.8.1-P1) on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04) and I am encountering some problems.

### External problem

When trying to check my DNS configuration with the following tools solvedns.com/biotechnics.ro and dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=biotechnics.ro they fail with output messages like "**Name server ns1.biotechnics.ro (89.36.94.53) does not answer queries**" or "**Your name server ns1.biotechnics.ro is NOT responding to NS record queries!**"

Also, external online dig tools such as [this](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php) give back the following output:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-P1 <<>> @ns1.biotechnics.ro -t NS biotechnics.ro
>
> ; (1 server found)
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

### Primary TLD from Parent

The parent is set up the following way:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-P1 <<>> @primary.rotld.ro -t NS biotechnics.ro
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7740
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;biotechnics.ro.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
biotechnics.ro.     10800   IN  NS  ns2.biotechnics.ro.
biotechnics.ro.     10800   IN  NS  ns1.biotechnics.ro.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.biotechnics.ro. 10800   IN  A   89.36.94.53
ns2.biotechnics.ro. 10800   IN  A   141.85.169.100

;; Query time: 279 msec
;; SERVER: 192.162.16.18#53(192.162.16.18)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 12 05:40:50 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

## Configuration on ns1

```
rsavu@host:/etc/bind$ head -40 named.conf
// ----------------------- Options -----------------------
options {
    // all relative paths use this directory as a base
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    // version statement changed for security (to avoid hacking known weaknesses)
    version "not currently available";
    // This prevents bind from serving other than authoritative requests:
    recursion no;
    // disables all zone transfer requests for performance as well as security reasons
    allow-transfer{none;};
    dnssec-enable no; // zone not signed
    minimal-responses yes; // optional - improved performance
    additional-from-auth no; // optional - improved performance
    additional-from-cache no; // optional - minimal performance change
};

// ----------------------- Logging -----------------------
// log to /var/log/named/zytrax-named all events from info UP in severity (no debug)
// uses 3 files in rotation swaps files when size reaches 250K
// failure messages up to this point are in (syslog) /var/log/messages
logging{
    channel custom_log{
        file "/var/log/bind9_info.log" versions 3 size 250k;
        severity debug;
    };
    category default{
        custom_log;
    };
};

// ----------------------- Zones -----------------------
zone "biotechnics.ro" in{
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.biotechnics.ro";
    allow-transfer { 141.85.169.100; };
    also-notify {141.85.169.100; };
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

## Zone file

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 36000      ; 10 hours
biotechnics.ro          IN SOA  ns1.biotechnics.ro. admin.biotechnics.ro. (
                                2013021201 ; serial
                                28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.biotechnics.ro.
                        NS      ns2.biotechnics.ro.
                        A       81.181.152.23
 $ORIGIN biotechnics.ro.
ftp                     A       81.181.152.23
ns1.biotechnics.ro.                     A       89.36.94.53
ns2.biotechnics.ro.                     A       141.85.169.100
www                     A       81.181.152.23
```

## What I checked

- There is no problem with the firewall (i disabled it for the moment)
- Dig from inside the hosts work
- Dig from slave works
- Putting recursion yes; doesn't solve the problem
- Netstat shows that port 53 is in use on UDP and TCP by named
- named-checkconf and named-checkzone issue no warning.

What can be the problem? Any ideas? I don't understand what's happening and why isn't my host replying to queries.

[Later edit] The slave is on Debian 4.0 and works very well (as you can see in the dns solvers above.

Comment: Have you used tcpdump to verify that the query is arriving on your server?

Comment: tcpdump udp and port 53 doesn't show any packages received. What can be the problem?

Comment: tcpdump shows packets arriving before any internal (iptables) firewall. It seems likely that your problem is outside Ubuntu. To be absolutely sure, run a tcpdump on a port configured with mirroring on the same switch that your server is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option

```
listen-on { 127.0.0.0/8; exter.nalip.addr.ess; };
```